Why is the LED bulb wattage limit in my lamps so much lower than the Incandescent limit?
My lamp specifies that the bulb limit is "60w Incandescent / 10w LED"
LEDs are more efficient and give off less heat. Shouldn't I be able to put in a higher wattage LED bulb? (regardless of the brightness difference)

It's likely that this isn't a safety thing - someone has guessed that a 60W incandescent is (very) roughly as bright as a 10W LED. Assuming this is a table lamp you wouldn't want to put anything bigger anyway.

Can you provide a links for this light?  Model #, shopping link, a photo, etc..   I have never seen a light rated this way.   If it is a fully enclosed fixture (complete glass dome over the bulb with no air flow) that would lend weight to the answers saying it is to protect the LED bulb itself from excessive heat.

@jay613, really? I see it all the time. Maybe it's a US-only thing? Here in the US, I'd be very surprised if you can't readily find such a fixture just browsing your favorite Big Box Store.

@Matthew I'm in the US.  To be fair, I have not shopped for or purchased a new fixture with bulb sockets in many years.  Everything I have bought for years has been designed for LED-only and usually integrated.   So if people are still making fixtures with E26 sockets and dual rating them maybe I'm in a self-imposed ignorance?  IDK.   I'll look.

@jay613, ugh, please don't encourage disposable light fixtures . Incidentally, IIRC my garage door opener is an example. But, yeah, you won't see ratings on things that don't let you replace the bulbs.

@Matthew I just looked at 10 ceiling fixtures from 9 manufacturers on 3 web sites.  6 were fully enclosed, 5 were multiple bulb.  Not a single one had a separate LED rating.   I was trying to find one and couldn't.  One came with a 7W filament LED but had only a 75W rating.  One said "two 60W incandescent or LED" explicitly allowing 120 watts of LED sunshine.

@Matthew Maybe.  1) $10 puck lights have a place in my life.  Mine are all RGB controllable too.  2) for the next step up, replicas of boob lights and other ceiling fixtures in the $11 to $100 range you don't have to dispose of them, you can install (LED Light Engines)[https://www.amazon.com/Euri-Lighting-EMP-2000cec-20-Dimmable-Compliant/dp/B0C3PZYCTQ/ref=sr_1_3_sspa]  and sometimes I'll do that to a brand new fixture to improve its lighting.  and 3) For the higher end of the market the LEDs are usually part of an artistic design, and you just hope the fixture is serviceable.

It's this cheap floor lamp purchased at Target in 2019: https://nmestateauctions.com/Event/LotDetails/16619513/60-Cantilever-Floor-Lamp

The slot for the bulb is thin metal surrounded by a fairly thick ceramic (or similar) material

Target still sells that lamp and their web site just says 60W.  The manufacturer also has a web site but with no specifications or manuals.  Where does it say 10W LED?  A sticker on the lamp?

Correct, a sticker on the lamp: "Caution: to reduce the risk of fire, use maximum 60 watt type A bulb or use maximum 10 watt self-ballasted LED lamp or lamp adapter 120V 60HZ AC only"

One possibility is the socket heat limit.
An incandescent bulb produces all of its heat in the middle of the bulb and away from the socket. The socket itself gets some heat, but not that much. If it gets 1/6 of the total heat then that's 10W.
On the other hand, many LED bulbs produce all of their heat in the socket. All (or nearly all) have their driver circuitry in the socket, and many also have the LEDs sitting right on top of the driver circuitry. (Some have the LEDs in the middle of the bulb for more even light dissipation and/or a more incandescent-like appearance.) So that's as much as 10W.
If the socket is designed to handle 10W of heat dissipation then 60W incandescent/10W LED is a reasonable combination.
Or it could be lazy engineers/cheap manufacturer that didn't want to really test things out to see how large an LED bulb would be safe.

most recent drivers i've seen are on a round al pcb at the border of the lens and base, with the heat coupled to the metal casing under the printed labling. Excepting candela-styles, LED bulb "sockets" run a lot cooler than old bulbs.

@dandavis "metal casing" already means you're not looking at the cheapest designs

I don't buy this!  Not DV'ing because it's interesting, but if it can handle a 60W incandescent, the socket will be ceramic, bakelite, or similar good to about 400°F, and it's not just temp but heat output .... no LED bulb that fits in a traditional light bulb housing produces that much heat energy,

The socket temperature need to remain below the temperature the LED electrics can cope with.  So unless deaigned with large heatsink, eg metal socket fixed to metal fitting it will damage overpowered LEDs.

I think this answers the question.  In a nutshell, incandescent bulbs radiate most of their heat out the front of the bulb as infrared (IR) radiation.  In fact a large portion of the electrical power into the bulb is turned into IR radiation, not visible light.  This is reason for their poor efficiency.  LED's while they generate less heat for the same light output, much of that heat is from the driver electronics located in the base.

LEDs and the light bulbs that use them don't like to get hot. Running hot significantly shortens their lifetime. So I suggest that the power rating for the fitting is what they exist it to be able to dissipate without the LED bulb getting too hot. It's normally the driver circuit that fails, and this isn't very well cooled by convection in most fittings.
I'd consider this more of a guideline for LEDs, unlike incandescent bulbs with their much greater heat load that leads to an actual hazard. But I'd still follow it, because I want to get my money's (and carbon footprint's) worth out of the bulbs, and the rating is normally plenty for a single source of light.

LED lights (the whole assemblies, not just the diodes) are producing less parasitic heat than incadescent lightbulbs for sure.
On the other hand LEDs are much more sensitive to temperatures.
Even though the new LED fits in the fixture and does not breach the limits for either the current rating and wattage (rated not to melt the insulation and the fixture structure) the heat produced by the LED might exceed temperature limit for the LED itself.
In more detail - LEDs are based on interface between two different semiconductors or semiconductor-metal interface. The material combination is selected the way that atoms in the interface get excited and deexcited regularly. As they deexcite they emmit radiation (Quantum meachanics!) in the visible (or infrared, or UV,...) range.
Another huge difference between incadescent lights and LEDs is in voltage. Incadescend lights can be built for any voltage. 1.5V? no problem; 1kV? no problem either. The voltage drop over LED interface is from milivolts to volts. There must be either low-voltage ("high" curent) circuitry or driver circuits to drop the voltage down from 230V to the proper one. This is based on pulse-width-modulation and is driven by "high-power" transistors. These also generate parasitic heat and they are also made of finely-structured semiconductors.
None of the semiconductors are "pure" metals or stoichiometric compounds - in other words, their microstructure is not stable. Increasing temperature "helps" diffusion and when the alloying elements near the interface diffund away and across the interface, the properties are gone for good.
The device may look unharmed to naked eye, it may look unharmed to microscope, it will be blown and you can indentify it with electron microscope with additional detectors (focused ion beam, energy dispersion spectroscopy).

I thought the usual failure-mode for all-in-1 LED bulbs was the driver in the base, not the LED junction itself.  The power electronics will usually be a switching power supply with some transistors, an inductor, and at least one capacitor.

The driver is based on Pulse-width-modulation that is driven by transistor - which is semiconductor-based as well and therefore heat sensitive as well. I will reword the answer.

An electrolytic capacitor as part of a rectifier is also common, and those are also heat-sensitive.  Apparently they're often the thing that fails, according to a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsIFxyOLJXM from a guy who seems to have some practical experience with the relevant electronics.  (Linked by Matthew under the question.)

Also, the forward bias voltage of an LED can't plausibly be just millivolts (under 0.01 V); that would mean the energy of the photons was very low, i.e. very long wavelength.  Hole+electron recombination is what emits light, with the photon energy being that many electron-volts (at least close to that).  For visible-light LEDs, it's a couple volts.  (Current tech of white LEDs are actually blue with a phosphor to generate the other frequencies, so they need higher voltage than green or red LEDs since blue is a shorter wavelength, higher energy photons.)

LEDs can we wired in series, e.g. the "filament" bulbs are often strings of LED so the actual voltage the driver need to produce can be higher.

My guess is they tested it with a 10W LED, to comply with some (perhaps new?) UL requirement, the test succeeded, and they couldn't be bothered testing higher wattage LEDs.    They may not have to regression-test everything, sometimes just establish safe guidelines.  10W was safe.  More testing costs money. Done.
I don't think the lamp manufacturer is trying to ensure the longevity of your LED bulbs. It's a good theory but I'm skeptical.
I routinely put LEDs far in excess of their incandescent equivalent into old light fixtures.  I monitor them carefully for heat but it's ridiculous, there is essentially zero heat compared to the old bulbs.  Sometimes the LED bulb life is compromised, sometimes drastically.  I don't care, I buy cheap bulbs and I love the light.

It can be boiled down this simple:

The incandescent bulb limit is fire safety related. The bulb itself can safely self-heat to a very high temperature, because it is made of glass and metal and a tiny amount of inorganic glue between them. E.g. 250C is pretty much OK. On the other hand, the materials that the fixture is made of, including but not limited to wiring, as well as the expected materials around (e.g. wood) are not this much tolerant. Assuming some model of heat exchange, one can estimate the maximum power where the bulb is e.g. 200C and the surrounding stuff neither ignites nor degrades way too quickly.

The LED bulb limit is related to the LED bulb itself. LEDs, as well as the accompanying electronics, are much more sensitive to the heat they generate than the incandescent bulb. LED bulbs in a fixture are also first to suffer from overheating, long before the materials around start to degrade from the heat. The limit could be placed around 60C at the bulb surface. Assuming a similar heat exchange model, one can get much lower power limit, generally 1/10 from the incandescent one.


